# Strtol is returning the wrong values

Tags: c

i just started learning c this week.

Im trying to convert single chars into long/int.
My problem is that when i call the convenrtCharToInt through the main , it is returing the right value , but when i call this function through another function , and give it a char that is inside an array of chars , im getting 10 instead of 1. i ever tried to input only *"1" into the function , and it is still giving me the wrong values , it give me 10 instead of 1 as a long.

```
double base2ToBase10(char test[],int curBase){

double totalSum;
long currentNumber;
int arrayLength=countArray(test);
for(int i=0; i<arrayLength ;i++) {
    currentNumber=convenrtCharToInt(test[i]);
    if ((test[i] < *"1")) {
        totalSum += 0;
    } else {
        totalSum += currentNumber*pow(curBase, arrayLength - 1 - i);

    }

}return totalSum;}

long convenrtCharToInt(char c)
{
    long postConvertValue = strtol ( &c,NULL, 10 );
    return postConvertValue;
```

so if i call it through the main it works , no matter how i do it , but if  i try to use it when i call base2ToBase10 it doesn't.

Comment: and why we have javascript tag here??

Comment: @Sanchit Patiyal I thought it was just me for a few seconds I thought I forgot everything about javascript.

Comment: weird it only show me that i tagged c

Comment: In `strtol ( &c,NULL, 10 )` you are not passing strtol a string, but a pointer to a single char, which is undefined behavior and all bets are off. `*"1"` is a convoluted way of writing `'1'`.

Comment: If your system uses ASCII (it does), you can just say `c-'0'` to get the value of a single digit, no need for strtoul. Alternatively you can do the entire conversion using `strtoul(test, NULL, curBase)`

Comment: Hi the c-"0" worked great! thanks.

Comment: @NickJH On any system, ASCII or not, you can just say `c-'0'`. The C11 standard guarantees that the digits from `0` to `9` use consecutive values. See section 5.2.1.

Comment: @David: probably just a typo, but note that `c-'0'` is very different from `c-"0"`.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner Why is it very diffrent?

Comment: `"0"` denotes a string literal, decaying to a pointer to a character. Hence, with `c-"0"` you substract a memory address from `c`, and this rarely makes sense. `'0'`, in contrast, is a character constant corresponding to ASCII code 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `&c` in

```
long convenrtCharToInt(char c) {
    long postConvertValue = strtol ( &c,NULL, 10 );
```

you pass a pointer to a single character to a function that expects a string in the sense of a `\0`-terminated sequence of characters. Hence, unless `c`'s value is `0`, function `strtol` will access memory out of the bounds of `c and thereby yield undefined behaviour.

To overcome this, you could simply write

```
int v = c - '0'; // substract ASCII-Code of digit '0' (i.e. 48)
return (v >= 0 && v <= 9) ? v : -1;
```

Comment: Thanks man , good solution and good explanation for the problem.